# Dynamically assign a variable based on the Tag

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, peoplesoft

The XML we recive can have either `<Cd>` or `<Prtry>` tag inside `<Rsn>` tag. I need a way to get the value inside either of the tag. The sample XML tag is given below.

Sample Xml1:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.002.001.03">
<CstmrPmtStsRpt>
<GrpHdr>
<MsgId>00000011</MsgId>
<CreDtTm>2016-02-10T01:37:43</CreDtTm>
<InitgPty>
<Id>
<OrgId>
<Othr>
<Id>XXXXXXXXX</Id>
</Othr>
</OrgId>
</Id>
</InitgPty>
<DbtrAgt>
<FinInstnId>
<ClrSysMmbId>
<ClrSysId>
<Cd>CACPA</Cd>
</ClrSysId>
<MmbId>12357677</MmbId>
</ClrSysMmbId>
<Nm>US001 NEW YORK OPERATIONS</Nm>
</FinInstnId>
</DbtrAgt>
<CdtrAgt>
<FinInstnId>
<ClrSysMmbId>
<ClrSysId>
<Cd>CACPA</Cd>
</ClrSysId>
<MmbId>1234567</MmbId>
</ClrSysMmbId>
<Nm>Test</Nm>
<PstlAdr>
<Ctry>CA</Ctry>
</PstlAdr>
</FinInstnId>
<BrnchId>
<Id>34642</Id>
</BrnchId>
</CdtrAgt>
</GrpHdr>
<OrgnlGrpInfAndSts>
<OrgnlMsgId>00000011</OrgnlMsgId>
<OrgnlMsgNmId>pain.001.001.03</OrgnlMsgNmId>
<OrgnlNbOfTxs>1</OrgnlNbOfTxs>
<GrpSts>RJCT</GrpSts>
</OrgnlGrpInfAndSts>
<OrgnlPmtInfAndSts>
<OrgnlPmtInfId>00000011/1</OrgnlPmtInfId>
    <TxInfAndSts>
    <OrgnlEndToEndId>TES000000001</OrgnlEndToEndId>
    <TxSts>RJCT</TxSts>
    <StsRsnInf>
     <Orgtr>
      <Id>
      <OrgId>
       <Othr>
        <Id>TEST123</Id>
       </Othr>
      </OrgId>
      </Id>
     </Orgtr>
     <Rsn>
      <Cd>TST01</Cd>
     </Rsn>
     <AddtlInf>SAMPLE TEXT</AddtlInf>
    </StsRsnInf>
<OrgnlTxRef>
<Amt>
<InstdAmt Ccy="USD">300</InstdAmt>
</Amt>
<ReqdExctnDt>2016-02-10</ReqdExctnDt>
<PmtTpInf>
<InstrPrty>HIGH</InstrPrty>
<SvcLvl>
<Prtry>NORM</Prtry>
</SvcLvl>
</PmtTpInf>
<PmtMtd>TRF</PmtMtd>
<Dbtr>
<Nm>Niagara Region</Nm>
<PstlAdr>
<PstCd>L2V 4T7</PstCd>
<TwnNm>Thorold</TwnNm>
<CtrySubDvsn>ON</CtrySubDvsn>
<Ctry>CA</Ctry>
<AdrLine>2201 St. David&apos;s Rd.</AdrLine>
</PstlAdr>
<Id>
<OrgId>
<Othr>
<Id>4455020000</Id>
<SchmeNm>
<Cd>BANK</Cd>
</SchmeNm>
<Issr>Niagara Region</Issr>
</Othr>
</OrgId>
</Id>
</Dbtr>
<DbtrAcct>
<Id>
<Othr>
<Id>0000182</Id>
</Othr>
</Id>
<Tp>
<Cd>CASH</Cd>
</Tp>
</DbtrAcct>
<DbtrAgt>
<FinInstnId>
<ClrSysMmbId>
<ClrSysId>
<Cd>CACPA</Cd>
</ClrSysId>
<MmbId>000304222</MmbId>
</ClrSysMmbId>
<Nm>Royal Bank of Canada</Nm>
<PstlAdr>
<PstCd>L2R 7G1</PstCd>
<TwnNm>St Catharines</TwnNm>
<CtrySubDvsn>ON</CtrySubDvsn>
<Ctry>CA</Ctry>
<AdrLine>80 King St</AdrLine>
<AdrLine>Suite #1</AdrLine>
</PstlAdr>
</FinInstnId>
</DbtrAgt>
<CdtrAgt>
<FinInstnId>
<ClrSysMmbId>
<ClrSysId>
<Cd>CACPA</Cd>
</ClrSysId>
<MmbId>000434642</MmbId>
</ClrSysMmbId>
<Nm>TD Canada Trust</Nm>
<PstlAdr>
<Ctry>CA</Ctry>
</PstlAdr>
</FinInstnId>
<BrnchId>
<Id>34642</Id>
</BrnchId>
</CdtrAgt>
<Cdtr>
<Nm>A Child&apos;s World Family Child Care Serv. - Niag.</Nm>
<PstlAdr>
<PstCd>L3B 6E5</PstCd>
<TwnNm>Welland</TwnNm>
<CtrySubDvsn>ON</CtrySubDvsn>
<Ctry>CA</Ctry>
<AdrLine>344 Avon Street</AdrLine>
</PstlAdr>
</Cdtr>
<CdtrAcct>
<Id>
<Othr>
<Id>04120728168</Id>
</Othr>
</Id>
<Tp>
<Cd>CASH</Cd>
</Tp>
</CdtrAcct>
</OrgnlTxRef>
</TxInfAndSts>
</OrgnlPmtInfAndSts>
</CstmrPmtStsRpt>
</Document>
```

OR

Part of Sample Xml2:

```
<TxInfAndSts>
<OrgnlEndToEndId>TES000000001</OrgnlEndToEndId>
<TxSts>RJCT</TxSts>
<StsRsnInf>
 <Orgtr>
  <Id>
  <OrgId>
   <Othr>
    <Id>TEST123</Id>
   </Othr>
  </OrgId>
  </Id>
 </Orgtr>
 <Rsn>
  <Prtry>TST01</Prtry>
 </Rsn>
 <AddtlInf>SAMPLE TEXT</AddtlInf>
</StsRsnInf>
```

The XML can either have `<Cd>` or `<Prtry>` but not both.

I am trying to dynamically assign a variable using "Choose" "When". The piece of XSLT is mentioned below

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:iso="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:pain.002.001.03" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8"/>
.........
<xsl:template match="iso:TxInfAndSts">
<xsl:variable name="ReasonCd">
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="iso:StsRsnInf/iso:Rsn/iso:Cd">
<xsl:value-of select="iso:StsRsnInf/iso:Rsn/iso:Cd"/>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:value-of select="iso:StsRsnInf/iso:Rsn/iso:Prtry"/>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable> 
<xsl:if test="string-length($ReasonCd) > 0 ">
<PMT_ACK_ERR class="R">
<PMT_ACK_FILE_ID/>
<PYMNT_REF_ID>
<xsl:apply-templates select="iso:OrgnlEndToEndId"/>
</PYMNT_REF_ID>
<SEQ_NUM>1</SEQ_NUM>
<ERROR_CODE>
<xsl:apply-templates select="$ReasonCd"/>
</ERROR_CODE>
<xsl:call-template name="iso:AddtlInf">
<xsl:with-param name="error_code">
<xsl:apply-templates select="$ReasonCd"/>
</xsl:with-param>
</xsl:call-template>
</PMT_ACK_ERR>
</xsl:if>
```

but its not working. The variable `ReasonCd` is not getting assigned. I tested using Online XSLT transformer and also ran in Peoplesoft Application Engine. Please let me know if there is any alternative way to assign the variable. The above code snippet is written on the Template match tag.

Comment: Your XMLs don't have a namespace, but your XSLT's XPath expressions do. How is that so?

Comment: "*The variable ReasonCd is not getting assigned.*" I am afraid you are mistaken about that. The variable **is** getting assigned. Look elsewhere for the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, we can't help you too much without seeing your **actual valid XML** and the full context of your variable declaration in a template.  You very likely have an issue with the context (which is why `$ReasonCd` is not getting assigned as desired), but you also have your logic currently set up to assign `$ReasonCd` the same value no matter what.  Try this template on your sample XML to see:

```
<xsl:template match="//StsRsnInf">
    <xsl:variable name="ReasonCd">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="Rsn/Cd">
                <xsl:value-of select="Rsn/Cd"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="'NotFound'"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable> 

    <xsl:value-of select="$ReasonCd" /> - <xsl:value-of select="Rsn/Cd" />
</xsl:template>
```

http://xsltransform.net/ncdD7mX